# SQL Server data modelling + spatial data = what book?

Tags: data, sql, sql-server, spatial-database, modelling

What recommended book can you provide about data modelling for geographical spatial data (geometry) in SQL server?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what sense of "data modeling" you mean? Are you talking about designing databases? Choosing (and processing) geometric abstractions to represent real-world features? Creating scientific and statistical models of geographic features?  Something else?

Comment: Q. Are you talking about designing databases? A. Yes      Q. Choosing (and processing) geometric abstractions to represent real-world features? A. yes     -

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This book isn't specifically about data modeling, but I have found it particularly useful for working with spatial data in SQL Server.

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Spatial-Server-Experts-Voice/dp/1430218290](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430218290)

There is also a newer book that will be more advanced and focused on SQL Server 2012, but I haven't looked at this myself yet.

[http://www.amazon.com/Spatial-Server-2012-Professional-Apress/dp/1430234911/ref=pd_sim_b_1/180-7129448-9163723](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430234911)